# Javascript : Console loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've just been challenged with the following question by a friend:

```
var i, n = 20;
for(i = 0; i < n; i--) console.log("-");
```

Q) Change a single symbol (change,delete,add) to make the code print "-" 20 times.

I've reached the following answers:

```
var i, n = 20;
for(i = 0; -i < n; i--) console.log("-");

var i, n = 20;
for(i = 0; i < n; n--) console.log("-");
```

He tells me there are three answers, but I can only come up with two.
Any ideas? This is driving me mad.

Comment: See: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8554/m3ph1st0ss-programming-puzzle-3-c-easy-bug

Comment: isn't that _this_ question?

Comment: @Eevee Exactly; infinite loop

Comment: @Eevee: Derp, wrong link! Thanks, updated :)

Comment: Woah, thanks! Neat link!

Comment: Why did Dolondro delete his answer, it works: `for(i = 0; i + n; i--) console.log("-");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i + n; i--) console.log("-");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make n MINUS 20

```
var i, n = -20;
for(i = 0; i < n; i--) console.log("-");
```

Comment: thanks @sachleen for editing my format. I thought I had that handled but then it messed up when I posted it

Comment: making n = -20, makes the 'i < n' false. The loop exits from the beginning.